# getBoundingClientRect() returning wrong width

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, svg

I'm using `Angular Material` for my grid system. I'm trying to generate an SVG and it is supposed to show me the width of the element, however it is `getBoundingClientRect()` is returning `300px` despite the width being `618px`. I tried it again making my window smaller but it still showed up as `300px` even though this time it was actually `100px`..

This is my HTML:

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap layout-padding>
    <div flex="33" ng-repeat="result in ctrl.results">
        <svg height="100%" width="100%" position>
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#da552f"></rect>
          <text fill="#ffffff" x="50%" y="50%" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="48" font-family="Verdana">Hello World</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my angularjs directive for the `position` attribute:

```
var app = angular.module('MainDirective', []);

app.directive('position', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            var rect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            var text = element.children()[1].getBBox();
            console.log(rect)
        }
    };
});
```

There is no custom CSS in my project.

Any thoughts why this might be happening? I've tried so many different variations of `getBoundingClientRect()` but they all returned `300`...

Edit: just as proof:

[image]

Comment: Where do you check `.width` of  `.getBoundingClientRect()` object?

Comment: @guest271314 within the `console.log(rect)`... you could technically do `console.log(rect.width)` I suppose.

Comment: Is `element[0]` `div` element? What does `console.log(window.innerWidth)` log at `console`? _"is returning `300px` despite the width being `618px`"_ Which element `width` is set to `618px`? _"There is no custom CSS in my project"_ How is element `width` set to `618px`?

Comment: `element[0] is the SVG and `console.log(window.innerWidth)` returns `1920`. When I check the Chrome dev tools and hover over the SVG it shows as `618px`.. as does the inner `rect`

Comment: The `width` of `svg` element is set to `100%` at the element `<svg height="100%" width="100%" position>`, not `618px`. `console.log(document.querySelector("svg").width.animVal.valueAsString, window.getComputedStyle(document.body).width)`.

Comment: @guest271314 Hmm very strange.. if I do `console.log(document.querySelector("svg").width.animVal)` it shows that `value` is set to `618` but if I do `console.log(document.querySelector("svg").width.animVal.value)` it returns as `300` again...

Comment: in which browser do you see this problem? chrome reports the right values for me...

Comment: What value do you want the `width` of the `<svg>` element to be to? `618px`? Or set to a dynamic `width` based on compasrison to another value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what my issue was.. I should've used angulars `$scope.$watch` as I was generating the `svg` on an event click.

```
var app = angular.module('MainDirective', []);

app.directive('position', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            var rect, image, text;
            $scope.$watch(element, function () {
                rect = element[0].clientWidth;
                image = element.children()[1].getBBox();
                text = element.children()[2].getBBox();
                console.log("Rect: "+rect+" image: "+image.width+" text: "+text.width)
            });
        }
    };
});
```